# Syntactic sugar for creating a pandas series with a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

The following code generates a Pandas series with a hierarchical MultiIndex:

```
import pandas as pd
number_of_classes = 3
number_of_price_brackets = 10
survival_table = pd.Series(
  index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(gender,klass,fare)
     for gender in range(2)
     for klass in range(number_of_classes)
     for fare in range(number_of_price_brackets)],
     names=['Gender','Class','Price Bracket']
     ))
```

But this approach seems a bit "manual". Is there any prettier way of generating the `survival_table` variable?

Answer (score 4):

Seems fine to me.

You could use `itertools.product` to create the tuples without the three `for` sections in the comprehension. But I think this is just as a good and will be readable for novices, whereas approaches with `itertools` are less so. The itertools way would be like this:

```
list(itertools.product(range(2), 
                       range(number_of_classes), 
                       range(number_of_price_brackets)))
```

You could also define a helper function if you find that you do this often.

```
def make_category_multiindex(categories, names):
    from itertools import product
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product(*categories)), names=names)
```

Then do:

```
categories = [range(2), 
              range(number_of_classes), 
              range(number_of_price_brackets)]

names = ['Gender','Class','Price Bracket']

survival_table = pd.Series(index=make_category_multiindex(categories, names))
```

Answer (score 3):

Same idea, different structure:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

column_names = ['Gender', 'Class', 'Price Bracket']
ranges = [range(2), range(3), range(10)]
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                            list(product(*ranges)), 
                            names=column_names)
survival_table = pd.Series(index=multi_index)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that Pandas 0.13 introduced pd.MultiIndex.from_product() that allows writing:

```
pandas.MultiIndex.from_product((range(2),
                                range(3),
                                range(10)),
                                names=['Gender','Class','Price Bracket'])
```